# retrieving dimensions of a Paperclip image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I am trying to retrieve dimensions of a Paperclip image. I tried calling methods `width` and `height` applied to each of my Imagemodel instances but these return errors.

Then I tried to get inspiration from this post : https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Extracting-image-dimensions

And played a bit in the console with the following :

```
image = Imagemodel.first
geometry = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image)
```

Though I get the following error in console

```
Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError:
```

So I am a bit confused... I am happy to either add height and width to specific fields in my table (but rather inside Create action in the controller rather than at model level) or directly accessing dimensions in my view or controller...

Comment: Are you sure the are actually passing the image. Iv just had ago via console and I can raise the same error as you if the file passed is actually blank.

Comment: you are correct. I retrieved full model instance which includes different fields on top of the actual image. I did `image = image.image` in the console and the geometry bit returned the image size as expected.. Now I can either use in my view or add some columns if needed ..

Comment: Awesome glad it helped. iv added pretty much what I said in the comment below as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you arent passing the image but actually the record itself.

Try this:

```
image = ImageModel.first.attachment # this assumes the actual image is named attachment
geometry = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image) # will return e.g. => 300x357
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me in Rails 4 was:

```
image = my_image_model.my_attachment.queued_for_write[:original]
Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image)
```